# Application Indicators not working on primary monitor

Tags: unity, indicator

I have a weird problem with Application Indicators in Unity. For example the Google Chrome indicator only appears on the left (primary) monitor, and clicking it with RMB/LMB works as expected. However the Synapse, Dropbox and Feedindicator's do not respond to any clicks at all, and they show up on both displays.  They can be used via right (secondary) monitor tho, but this is quite annoying.

I've set systray-whitelist to ['all'] since I CBA to whitelist on-app-basis and this is when the problem begun (I'm sure I could click Dropbox on both monitors, but then again when it wasn't whitelisted I think it was using the new system instead of an Applet Indicator).

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2188345/problem.png]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGaRO.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have resolved itself now. I haven't done any changes and been rebooting machine regularly, so must have been some update or just "magic". :)